# Under what conditions would the dot product for (vectorX + vectorY) and (vectorX - vectorY) be zero?

Tags: calculus, geometry, functions, vectors, vector-analysis

I am stuck on a homework question:

```
3.a) Under what conditions would the dot product of (vectorX + vectorY) and (vectorX - vectorY) = 0?
  b) Draw a vector (X) and a vector (Y) according to the conditions in part (a) and then using the diagram, show the truth of the statement in part (a).
```

For part a), the only condition I could find was that (vectorX + vectorY) and (vectorX - vectorY) had to be perpendicular, however, I am unsure as to how I am supposed to isolate for either vector X or vector Y in this case. Help would be greatly appreciated and thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know that $\|x\|^2=x\cdot x$ and we know the dot product is both commutative, i.e. $a\cdot b=b\cdot a$, and distributive, i.e. $(a+b)\cdot c=a\cdot c+b\cdot c$.

Now, what can you say about $(x+y)\cdot (x-y)=0$?